# The Ruby `exit!` function appears to call exit handlers contrary to documentation

Tags: ruby, jruby

The following code run on JRuby 9.1.17.0 and 9.2.13.0 on Windows:

```
at_exit { puts "at_exit function" }
ObjectSpace.define_finalizer("string",  proc { puts "in finalizer" })
exit!
```

produces this:

```
at_exit function
in finalizer
```

My expectation was that the exit handlers should not have been called as per the documentation for `exit!`:
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exit-21

Is this a bug in `exit!`?

Is there some other way that I can achieve the desired outcome of not firing exit handlers so that I can guarantee killing my system from the inside?

Comment: In MRI 2.7.1 your code produces no output. Might be worth noting that JRuby and MRI are different implementations of Ruby and the link to the documentation you posted is for MRI.

Comment: Yes @spickermann.  It does work as specified with MRI.  As such, it does appear to be a bug with JRuby.

Comment: I have raised a bug report on JRuby:  https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/6379

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a known incompatibility in JRuby.

The specs for [`Kernel#exit!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exit-21) and [`Process::exit!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Process.html#method-c-exit-21) were only added to [`ruby/spec`](https://github.com/ruby/spec) on July, 27th 2020 (35 days ago) by Benoit Daloze (maintainer of `ruby/spec`, lead developer of TruffleRuby, JRuby Team Member): https://github.com/ruby/spec/commit/3bf0edcecb424df1e3a70fe48971b24af4be1977#diff-5b2f13aa6d64a30812e9221d9994b907R95-R99

On July, 28th 2020, Benoit added tags to the JRuby `spec` directory disabling those new specs as known failures: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/commit/f138bd9e62b757e6fd209101b2eb46b266b9b7b0#diff-332fe3279d2469ab891d8739c3d425e3R1-R2

The JRuby team *does* run the `ruby/spec`s to ensure compatibility with all other Ruby implementations, but of course if specs are missing, incompatibilities may slip through unnoticed.

Comment: Considering nobody noticed in 19 years, it doesn't seem to be a high-priority fix, though.

Comment: It's a priority for me.    Not enough for me to attempt to patch the JRuby code though. 
Oh well.